# Ibatis data migration issue

Tags: java, sql, ibatis

How do I solve this error when using ibatis for data migration between two SQL databases in my java project.The Stacktrace I get is as follows.

> INFO: Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'projproject'
>           [EL Config]: 2012-10-18 15:20:56.439--ServerSession(257101811)--Connection(904190158)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--disconnect
>       [EL Info]: 2012-10-18 15:20:56.439--ServerSession(257101811)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--file:/var/tmp/tproject/lib/project-domain-0.9.28.jar_projproject logout successful
>       Oct 18, 2012 3:20:56 PM org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver destroy
>       INFO: Removing all registered transformers for class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader
>       Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: SqlMapClient operation; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [null]; error code [0];
>       --- The error occurred in tproject-migration-sql-map.xml.
>       --- The error occurred while applying a result map.
>       --- Check the TprojectMigration.findOrders-AutoResultMap.
>       --- The error happened while setting a property on the result object.
>       --- Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
>       --- The error occurred in tproject-migration-sql-map.xml.
>       --- The error occurred while applying a result map.
>       --- Check the TprojectMigration.findOrders-AutoResultMap.
>       --- The error happened while setting a property on the result object.
>       --- Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
>               at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:203)
>               at com.proj.project.migration.tproject.TprojectDaoImpl.queryForOrders(TprojectDaoImpl.java:257)
>               at com.proj.project.migration.migrator.order.OrderMigrator.migrateOrders(OrderMigrator.java:137)
>               at com.proj.project.migration.MigrationClient.migrate(MigrationClient.java:94)
>               at com.proj.project.migration.MigrationClient.main(MigrationClient.java:161)
>       Caused by: com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
>       --- The error occurred in tproject-migration-sql-map.xml.
>       --- The error occurred while applying a result map.
>       --- Check the TprojectMigration.findOrders-AutoResultMap.
>       --- The error happened while setting a property on the result object.
>       --- Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I am performing data migration between two sql database using Ibatis.

Comment: Not enough information, submit description, some of the code for that, please.

Comment: We need more context. Please post a question first, and follow it with logs or a stack trace.

Comment: The above one is a stacktrace.

Comment: "The error occurred while applying a result map. --- Check the TprojectMigration.findOrders-AutoResultMap. --- The error happened while setting a property on the result object"

Comment: Yes fixed it the provider which provided the data was null as we had disabled the code for retrieving the data from the provider.